# Как эффективно выбрать из DataFrame строки во временных интервалах?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть DataFrame:

```
                    DATE     DECDATE         HAE         HAN       HK2  
0       2020:01:01:00:00  1577793600  135.080287  719.287209  8.352746   
1       2020:01:01:00:01  1577793660  135.076589  719.294816  8.351585   
2       2020:01:01:00:02  1577793720  135.087681  719.291013  8.351263   
3       2020:01:01:00:03  1577793780  135.079054  719.303691  8.350585   
4       2020:01:01:00:04  1577793840  135.092611  719.312567  8.352230   
5       2020:01:01:00:05  1577793900  135.075357  719.293548  8.353165   
6       2020:01:01:00:06  1577793960  135.076589  719.291013  8.353584   
7       2020:01:01:00:07  1577794020  135.090146  719.297352  8.353165   
8       2020:01:01:00:08  1577794080  135.086449  719.307495  8.352585   
9       2020:01:01:00:09  1577794140  135.069195  719.293548  8.353455   
 ........
```

Столбец `DECDATE` содержит время в секундах от начала эпохи (1 января 1970г). Необходимо выбрать строки в последовательных интервалах времени. Допустим, каждый временной интервал составляет 3 минуты.

Пробовал так:

```
frst=df.loc[0,'DECDATE'] #Первое значение в столбце
for every in df['DECDATE']:
           intrvl=frst+180 #К первому значению прибавляем 3 минуты в секундах
           sample=df[df[df['DECDATE']>=frst]<intrvl]
           #sample=df.query("frst <= DECDATE < intrvl") 
           frst=intrvl
```

Похоже, из за цикла обработка файла длиной год происходит **очень** долго. Пока ничего лучше не придумал.

Comment: Выбрать строки несложно. Но чтобы ускорить цикл нужно понимать что вы хотите делать с переменной “sample” на каждой итерации цикла.

Comment: На каждой итерации данные   в столбцах  HAE, HAN, HK2  будут осредняться в пределах интервала и записываться в другой dataframe. Т. е. вместо интервала получаем одну строку  с теми же столбцами, что и в исходной переменной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = df.set_index(pd.to_datetime(df['DECDATE'], unit='s')).resample('3T').mean()
```

---

результат:

```
In [7]: res
Out[7]:
                        DECDATE         HAE         HAN       HK2
DECDATE
2019-12-31 12:00:00  1577793660  135.081519  719.291013  8.351865
2019-12-31 12:03:00  1577793840  135.082341  719.303269  8.351993
2019-12-31 12:06:00  1577794020  135.084395  719.298620  8.353111
2019-12-31 12:09:00  1577794140  135.069195  719.293548  8.353455
```

или так:

```
In [8]: res.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[8]:
      DECDATE         HAE         HAN       HK2
0  1577793660  135.081519  719.291013  8.351865
1  1577793840  135.082341  719.303269  8.351993
2  1577794020  135.084395  719.298620  8.353111
3  1577794140  135.069195  719.293548  8.353455
```

---

**более быстрый вариант (без парсинга даты и времени):**

```
In [15]: cols = ['HAE', 'HAN', 'HK2']

In [16]: res = df.groupby(df['DECDATE'] // 180 * 180)[cols].mean().reset_index()

In [17]: res
Out[17]:
      DECDATE         HAE         HAN       HK2
0  1577793600  135.081519  719.291013  8.351865
1  1577793780  135.082341  719.303269  8.351993
2  1577793960  135.084395  719.298620  8.353111
3  1577794140  135.069195  719.293548  8.353455
```

Answer (score 2):

Для

```
                    DATE     DECDATE         HAE         HAN       HK2  
0       2020:01:01:00:00  1577793600  135.080287  719.287209  8.352746   
1       2020:01:01:00:01  1577793660  135.076589  719.294816  8.351585   
2       2020:01:01:00:02  1577793720  135.087681  719.291013  8.351263   
3       2020:01:01:00:03  1577793780  135.079054  719.303691  8.350585   
4       2020:01:01:00:04  1577793840  135.092611  719.312567  8.352230   
5       2020:01:01:00:05  1577793900  135.075357  719.293548  8.353165   
6       2020:01:01:00:06  1577793960  135.076589  719.291013  8.353584   
7       2020:01:01:00:07  1577794020  135.090146  719.297352  8.353165   
8       2020:01:01:00:08  1577794080  135.086449  719.307495  8.352585   
9       2020:01:01:00:09  1577794140  135.069195  719.293548  8.353455
```

```
df['DECDATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DECDATE'], unit='s')
res =df.groupby(pd.Grouper(key='DECDATE', freq='3Min')).mean()
```

соответственно, res будет:

```
                            HAE         HAN       HK2
DECDATE                                              
2019-12-31 12:00:00  135.081519  719.291013  8.351865
2019-12-31 12:03:00  135.082341  719.303269  8.351993
2019-12-31 12:06:00  135.084395  719.298620  8.353111
2019-12-31 12:09:00  135.069195  719.293548  8.353455
```